# Bootstrap : affix + carousel + spy does not work correctly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I develop a new website (http://learning-happly.azurewebsites.net). I try to do it with Bootstrap scripts (scrollspy, carousel, affix). But, affix doesn’t works correctly in Safari and Chrome:

My page is 
- Header 
  - Carousel 
  - #brands-menu (to affix)
- Content of landing page
as :

```
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- height : $(window).height() - $("#brands-menu").height() (before scripts) -->
        <section id="carousel">
        </section>

        <!-- height : 159px, to affix -->
        <div id="brands-menu">
            <div id="brands">
                … 
            </div>
            <nav id="menu">
                …
            </nav>
        </div> 
    </header>
    <section>
        … 
    </section>
    …
    <script>
        // make carousel
        $('#carousel').carousel();

        // scrollspy (159 is the height of affixed #brands-menu)
        $('#menu').scrollspy({ offset:159 });

        // to scroll to landing page items
        $('#brands-menu').scroll_navi();

        // affix brands and menu, when scroll hides #carousel
        $("#brands-menu").affix({ offset:{top:$("#carousel").height(), bottom:0}});
    </script>
</body>
```

Result : http://learning-happly.azurewebsites.net

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ and also check out the error console in developer tools in Chrome, you will see other errors.